# USB 3.0 card not no connections

Tags: boot, drivers, usb

Got a netbook with a 3 port USB 3.0 card in it.

If I plug a USB 3.0 hard drive in it. It don't light up. It's like no power or don't see it.

```
root@fujitsu-laptop:~# dmesg | grep -i usb3
[    0.782377] usb usb3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 5.04
[    0.783227] usb usb3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    0.784073] usb usb3: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    0.784911] usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 5.4.0-31-generic xhci-hcd
[    0.785750] usb usb3: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    4.160291] input: FJ Camera : FJ Camera  as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4:1.0/input/input26
root@fujitsu-laptop:~#
```

Have Ubuntu 20.04 server on it. How can get this USB 3.0 to work? There is no USB 3.0 built in to this netbook. That's why I got the card.

Comment: This card came with a mini CD but only a Windows .exe file on it. "FL1100 Driver" says on the disk label. It this helps.

Comment: Phpsysinfo will show this about it: USB controller: Fresco Logic FL1100 USB 3.0 Host Controller